# how insert data from combo/list box to mysql by using phpmyadmin

Tags: html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have designed form which has list/combo box, which has 5-6 values.
I require that when any one value is selected that value should get recorded in database. I am using phpMyAdmin for creating database. 
please let me know how I could insert those values from combo/list box to mysql by using phpmyadmin. and how to bind it with MySQL.

My html codes are as follows

```
<select name="select5" id="label36">
    <option selected="selected">Cash</option>
    <option>Cheque</option>
    <option>DD</option>
    <option>Online Transfer</option>
</select>
```

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is just a front-end tool to manipulate data in a mysql database, you can't send or get data from that tool to your website. You need an application layer - maybe written PHP or .. anything - to connect to the database and then get / save data to it. Search around for some solutions first, there's too many to possibly suggest here.

Comment: can you put the php you tried?